# Installing HTC Legend ROM on emulator

Tags: android-emulator, legend, rom

For layout testing purposes I would like my AVD to look exactly like an HTC Legend.
I downloaded:

```
RUU_Legend_HTC_WWE_2.03.405.3_Radio_47.39.35.09_7.08.35.21_release_130330_signed.exe
```

Started the AVD and then the installer. The ROM update tool recognizes the emulator as an Android device: (Doh - can't upload the screenshot because of stackoverflow's rules. Anyways it says:)

From:
Imageversion:
google_sdk-eng

To:
Imageversion:
2.03.405.3

Unfortunately it freezes at 'Restarting to Bootloader' - I can close the emulator and start it up again, but the installer keeps writing 'Waiting for Bootloader... ( N) ...'

Maybe an easier approach would be to try and find the system.img file inside the install package. Anyone tried doing this?

Comment: ROM update tool screenshot: http://i56.tinypic.com/kvxty.png

Answer (score 0):

I got the system.img and various other files onto my AVD:

1. Go to C:\Documents and Settings\[Username]\Local Settings\Temp
2. Start ROM update tool and go into the 2nd directory created
   (mine was C:\Documents and Settings\[Username]\Local Settings\Temp\{C8465DBB-B65C-48D8-AE23-B3E98E45D61C}\{50F2F878-636A-496F-A7CB-544C067E0C4B})
3. Open rom.zip and unpack .img's & .nb0's to your AVD directory (C:\Documents and Settings\[Username]\.android\avd\HTC_Legend.avd)

Unfortunately the emulator just keeps rebooting - it just plays the HTC startup sound again and again.